# Why does the multinomial coefficient count the same numbers as the combination coefficient?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations, multinomial-coefficients

[image]

I do not fully grasp the intuition of this. Is the reasoning behind the equality due to the fact that they're simply counting the combinations disregarding the order? For example, counting the arrangements of letters with duplicates, the multinomial coefficient cuts down the undistinguished arrangements due to the duplicates.

Comment: They are not always the same, but they are the same in the case in the image. You can see this by writing out $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and $\binom{n}{k, n-k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: The multinomial coefficient in this case counts the number of ways to split an $n$-element set into two labeled subsets, the first with $k$ elements and the second with $n-k$ elements. This is like what the binomial coefficient is doing: You are picking $n$ elements to be in a subset, and the remaining $n-k$, consequently, are not in your subset. But this can also be thought of as splitting your original $n$-element set into two labeled subsets: one labeled "picked" and the other labeled "not picked".